# Can you use the JDBC adapter on MRI ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

We're dealing with OCI issues with MRI Ruby and would like to use the gem `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` to simplify the process.  Is it possible to use JDBC with MRI Ruby?  I've started down the rabbit hole of `oracle-enhanced` and `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` but it looks like there's no straight forward way.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. JDBC will only work on the JRE, and MRI Ruby has nothing to do with the JRE.

Comment: You would need to be using JRuby to use JDBC, and it's not 100% compatible with MRI ruby so you can't just switch to it usually.

Comment: ok.  I wasn't sure if I had a JRE installed if there was a way for it to work.